# Oracle Job not been executed for no reason

Tags: oracle, jobs, dbms-job

Im programing a job in oracle in order to execute a store procedure, but when the time comes it just does not happend any thing for no reason.

Is there some kind of log where I can see if an error happend or something?

Im using the dbms_job package to create the job

Tnks.

Comment: Are you using DBMS_JOB or DBMS_SCHEDULER to execute the job?

Comment: Looks like it might be from this site: http://www.orafaq.com/node/871. If so, it's DBMS_JOB functionality.

Comment: Yes I used that sentence to create the job: 

declare
  my_job number;

it creates it, but when the time comes, it doesnt execute
begin
  dbms_job.submit(job => my_job, 
    what => 'my_procedure(foo);'
    next_date => sysdate+1,
    interval => 'sysdate+1');
end;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're using DBMS_JOB

- Are you committing after making the call to DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT?  Your job can't run until you've committed.
- Have you set JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES to a non-zero value?  Are there any other DBMS_JOB jobs running in your system?
- Can you post the results of running the following query:

> ```
> SELECT last_date, 
>        last_sec, 
>        next_date, 
>        next_sec, 
>        this_date, 
>        this_sec, 
>        broken, 
>        failures, 
>        total_time
>   FROM dba_jobs
>  WHERE job = <<your job number>>
> ```

Comment: You type "commit" after calling dbms_job.submit.

Comment: Aside from Justin's excellent answer see the Oracle documentation: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_job.htm#i1000807

Comment: I forgot to COMMIT after DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT, thank you very much for your answer!